# Problems with two-step verification on a new SIM

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sim-card, 2-step-verification

I recently purchased a new SIM. When I try to install WhatsApp, it asks for a PIN that was apparently created by the previous owner for two-step verification. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what is the problem - you purchased a SIM that had a previous owner? That's kind of unusual... Have you followed [these steps](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/27585377/?category=5245246)?

Answer (score 2):

I just experienced the same problem and according to WhatsApp support there is no real solution for it.

I also got a new SIM with a phone number that was used by someone else before. This previous users WhatsApp account had two-step verification activated which means I couldn't activate WhatsApp since it was asking for the pin that I don't have and that can only be reset with an e-mail adress that is not mine.

The answer from WhatsApp support is to wait 7 days and then I will be able to reset the account without the pin. They said there is no alternative or other way to speed up the process.

**Update** 
The account reset worked as expected after 7 days.
Any messages that I might have received in the meantime were not delivered and deleted.

This whole process doesn't seem very optimal to me.